# PNG losing alpha channel when uploaded

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using amazon s3 to store images. When I upload a PNG file, the alpha channel is lost, such as below:

[image]

```
ObjectMetadata metaData= new ObjectMetadata();
metaData.setContentType("image/png");

BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(creds);

client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket,  objectName, file, metaData).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and defining `Content-Length` explicitly solved the issue.

Also look at: 
[git-hub/easy-thumbnails](http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/337) .
I didn't delve in, but it seems there is a way to force S3 to keep transparency.